# Use other operator than "in" in python with "match" function

Tags: python, match

This can be kind a very little question but I couldn't find anything about it.
As we can use `in` operator to check the partial element of a sequence. We can use `in` with `if` statement to check any particular element of sequence. for example.

```
a='stackoverflow'
if 'over' in a:
   print(a)
else:
   print("error")
```

Just like this, I want to use `match` statement to check the partial element of a sequence. But I'm unable to use `in` operator with `match`.
Can anyone help me implement this thing.......

```
a = 'stackoverflow'
match a:
   case 'over':
      print(a)
   case _:
      print("error")
```

If there is a way please let me know.

Comment: The title contradicts the question body.

Comment: @user3840170 I seriously didn't know what should be the title. That's why......

Answer (score 2):

Just use it like this:

```
a = 'stackoverflow'
match a:
    case _ if 'over' in a:
        print(a)
    case _:
        print("error")
```

Comment: I also get a syntax error when running in `Python 3.11.0`

Comment: @MDDANISH My bad, i updated the solution. Its not that pretty to be honest. But thats the only way to do it, if you want to force the use of "case" ...

Comment: @sd3v Thank you so much man. But if there is more cases then I have to use if-else ladder in match case also. I wanted to make this process faster but I don't think it'll be possible. It'll better if I directly use if-else ladder.

Comment: anyway - match/case in current Python (up to 3.12) is not faster than using "if/else" - and it likely won't ever be, due to the nature of the features themselves .